# If I want to transfer Gta from 360 to ps4 do I need to have Xbox gold to transfer to ps4

Tags: xbox-360, ps4, grand-theft-auto-online

Like I know I need ps4 plus to actually go online but do I need to also have gold for this to happen

Comment: [Doesn't look like it](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/202892778-Transferring-Your-Previous-Grand-Theft-Auto-Online-Characters-and-Progression-to-PlayStation-4-Xbox-One-or-PC). Mentions you need Gold for transfer to XBOX, not to transfer from XBOX to PS4.

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need XBL Gold for you to transfer from Xbox to PS4. Here are **[instructions](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/202892778-Transferring-Your-Previous-Grand-Theft-Auto-Online-Characters-and-Progression-to-PlayStation-4-or-Xbox-One)** that walk you through the process of transferring as well.

**In short:** Once you have made your PS4 account you will need to link your GTA social club account and XBL account. Then when you sign in you should be prompted to start the transfer.